# Simple random walk bound hitting problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am trying to understand the example 2.2. from [this course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_S096F13_lecnote5.pdf)

It is below. However, I am struggling to understand a key step in the reasoning. Specifically, I don't understand why this statement is true.

```
If we let f(−B + 1) = α, then it follows that f(−B + r) = αr for all r ≤ A + B.
```

given this the solution is obvious algebra, but I just don't understand this at all. Any help would be appreciated.

> Suppose that a gambler plays the following game. At each turn the
> dealer throws an un-biased coin, and if the outcome is head the
> gambler wins $1, while if it is head she loses \$1. If each coin toss
> is independent, then the balance of the gambler has the distribution
> of the simple random walk.
>
> For two positive integers A and B, what is the probability that the
> random walk reaches A before it reaches −B? Let τ be the first time at
> which the random walk reaches either A or −B. Then Xτ = A or −B.
> Define f(k) = P(Xτ = A | X0 = k), and note that our goal is to compute
> f(0). The recursive formula f(k) =
> 0.5 f(k + 1) + 0.5 f (k −1) follows from considering the outcome of the first cointoss. We also have the boundary conditions f(A) = 1,
> f(−B) = 0. If we let f(−B + 1) = α, then it follows that f( 1 −B + r)
> = αr for all r ≤ A + B. Therefore, α = A+B , and it follows that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this by induction, and rearranging the formula to the form:

$$f(k) = 2f(k-1) - f(k-2)$$.

Supposing $f(-B + s) = \alpha s$ for $1 \leq s \leq r-1$ then

$$
\begin{align}
f(-B + r) & = 2f(-B + r-1) - f(-B +r - 2) \\
& = 2\alpha(r-1) - \alpha(r-2) \\
& = \alpha r.
\end{align}
$$